# Proguard obfuscation has made it 'impossible' for updated versions of my communication-based app to be compatible with messaging older versions

Tags: android, deserialization, proguard, kryo

A part of my app works by transmitting serialised object data across the internet, between two devices, and deserialising on the other end (through use of the Kryo library). Proguard has obfuscated the names of these classes, but I realise now that I should have kept the serialised classes unobfuscated so that future updates to the app would still have consistent class names. However it is too late for this now.

Future updates can either be obfuscated differently by Proguard, or have the serialised classes unobfuscated. Either way, it means that crashes will occur when older and newer versions of my app try to communicate with each other, as an old version will send an object that cannot be deserialised by a new version due to the mismatch of class names (which must be provided to the Kryo method calls).

This has left me in a position where I'm not sure how I can provide future updates to my app without annoying my users with these potential crashes while new versions are rolled out. Does the only real course of action involve having to go through such a period until everyone is up to date with each other?

I would appreciate any advice on the best way to handle this tricky situation.

Comment: For anyone else who encounters this question, do not use this sort of code-centric serialization (Kryo or otherwise) for on-the-wire data formats. First, it locks you into one platform (the OP is screwed if he ever wants to support iOS, Web apps, etc.). Second, problems like the OP is encountering will crop up. On-the-wire data formats are interface, not implementation, and interfaces need to be intentionally named. Use XML, JSON, protobuf, or something where the data format names are independent of the code that generates or parses the data format.

Comment: "Does the only real course of action involve having to go through such a period until everyone is up to date with each other?" -- since nobody has to update the app, the period may be infinite. I'd look into seeing if there is a way that you can control the Proguard obfuscation rules to lock you into the old names, while in parallel you start offering data exchange in something more flexible.

Comment: Thank you, and yes you're entirely correct in your first comment. With hindsight I definitely wouldn't have done it this way, but I'm stuck with the mess now.

Comment: Another possibility, ugly as it will be, is to actually rename the affected classes and methods to the obfuscated versions from your shipping app. Then, you can tell Proguard to just `keep` those classes, and your original obfuscated names should remain intact.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the comments by CommonsWare you can use Proguard's [`-applymapping` *filename*](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#applymapping) option for the affected classes/fields/methods. Here, *filename* refers to the copy of a saved mapping file from a previous Proguard run. In your case, I suggest to remove everything unaffected from this file so only the obfuscated names for the affected classes etc. are kept.